# Passing arguments when loading custom CodeIgniter library

Tags: php, codeigniter, arguments, class-library

I'm trying to implement a class I've written as CodeIgniter library.

Somehow I can't get CI's `load()` method to pass multiple arguments to the class's constructor function.

My class is designed to get 3 arguments, 2 arrays and one optional string.

The constructor looks somewhat like this:

```
public function __construct($array, $array,$string=""){
/** code **/
}
```

The relevant part from the controller:

```
function index(){
  $array1 = array('key1'=>'value','key2'=>'value');
  $array2 = array('key1'=>'value','key2'=>'value');
  $string = "value";
  $params = array($array1,$array2,$string);
  $this->load->library("MyClass",$params);
}
```

Loading the controller generates this error :

```
Message: Missing argument 2 for MyClass::__construct()
```

This is really puzzling me. It seems the first argument gets sent fine and then it chokes on the second argument. Any clues on why this is happening will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate:  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149098/php-codeigniter-how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-model

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to modify your class constructor to handle the passed data as described here:

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

```
public function __construct($params)
{
    $array1 = $params[0];
    $array2 = $params[1];
    $string = $params[2];

    // Rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Actually, I recommend using an associative array to pass data into the constructor. This makes for more readable code, makes optional arguments easier to use, and is more consistent with the built-in libraries.

Comment: the link is not valid, should be http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html nowdays

Answer (score 0):

Passing Parameters When Initializing Your Class

In the library loading function you can dynamically pass data as an array via the second parameter and it will be passed to your class constructor:

```
$params = array('type' => 'large', 'color' => 'red');
```

$this->load->library('Someclass', $params);
If you use this feature you must set up your class constructor to expect data:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Someclass {

    public function __construct($params)
    {
        // Do something with $params
    }
}

?>
```