# PHP / CodeIgniter- Undefined variable in class construct

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, object, arguments

I have the following php errors :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: t

and

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Missing argument 1 for myclass::__construct(), called in
>   xxx on line 1011
>   and defined

My controller contains :

```
    $this->load->model('mymodel');
    $i = $this->mymodel->func(1);
    print_r($i);
```

mymodel :

```
$test = new myclass("foo", "bar");
$myarray[] = $test;
return $myarray
```

myclass :

```
class myclass {

var $a;
var $b;

public function __construct($t, $l) // ERROR 2
{
    $this->a = $t; // ERROR 1
    $this->b = $l;
}

}
```

Note that print_r($a) in controller prints the correct object with content..

Thanks

Comment: PHP gives you the line numbers of the errors. Why don't you post that code…

Comment: You're right, I edited code with // ERROR in front of concerned lines.

Comment: It's not possible. Create some robust 1-file example and put it on pastebin.com so we can run it and see the issue

Comment: Let's see the code on line 1011. Is $this->load->model('mymodel') constructing myclass? Is $this->model->func(1) constructing myclass? It's hard to tell without a more complete look at the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, that was caused by Codeigniter.

*myclass* is declared in a separate file and loaded by *mymodel* using :

```
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('myclass', $params);
```

When loading the library, Codeigniter  creates an instance of *myclass* as a singleton, but it doesn't transmit any argument. To prevent this error, you have to give parameters before loading the lib :

```
    $params = array('type' => "a", 'loc' => "b");
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('myclass', $params);
```

Note that it **must** be an array ($params), not a single argument.

Answer (score 0):

another way is to copy-cat antelove [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52122854/2368696).

with that way, you only need change the model file and the way you load the model.

P.S this is just to enrich this SO thread